# Replacing first character in line in multi-line text column

Tags: r, regex, text, gsub

I am trying to replace the "o " with "• " in this text:

> • Direct the Department’s technical
>
> • Perform supervisory and managerial responsibilities as leader of the program
>
> o Set direction to ensure goals and objectives
>
> o Select management and other key personnel
>
> o Collaborate with executive colleagues to develop and execute corporate initiatives and
> department strategy
>
> o Oversee the preparation and execution of department’s Annual Financial Plan and budget
>
> o Manage merit pay
>
> • Perform other duties as assigned

Since these are at the beginning of the line I've tried

```
test<- sub(test, pattern = "o ", replacement = "• ")  # does not work
test<- gsub(test, pattern = "^o ", replacement = "• ")  # does not work
test<- gsub(test, pattern = "o ", replacement = "• ") # works but it also replaces to to t•
```

Why does "^o " not work since it only appears at the beginning of each the line

Comment: `^o` works, are you sure you shared the right strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is all in a single value? If so, use a lookbehind to find `o` following either line breaks or string start:

```
test2 <- gsub(test, pattern = "(?<=\n|\r|^)o ", replacement = "• ", perl = TRUE)
cat(test2)
```

```
• Direct the Department’s technical

• Perform supervisory and managerial responsibilities as leader of the program

• Set direction to ensure goals and objectives

• Select management and other key personnel

• Collaborate with executive colleagues to develop and execute corporate initiatives and department strategy

• Oversee the preparation and execution of department’s Annual Financial Plan and budget

• Manage merit pay

• Perform other duties as assigned
```

Alternatively, split into individual values per line, then use your original regex:

```
test3 <- gsub(unlist(strsplit(test, "\n|\r")), pattern = "^o ", replacement = "• ")
test3
```

```
 [1] "• Direct the Department’s technical"                                                                         
 [2] ""                                                                                                            
 [3] "• Perform supervisory and managerial responsibilities as leader of the program"                              
 [4] ""                                                                                                            
 [5] "• Set direction to ensure goals and objectives"                                                              
 [6] ""                                                                                                            
 [7] "• Select management and other key personnel"                                                                 
 [8] ""                                                                                                            
 [9] "• Collaborate with executive colleagues to develop and execute corporate initiatives and department strategy"
[10] ""                                                                                                            
[11] "• Oversee the preparation and execution of department’s Annual Financial Plan and budget"                    
[12] ""                                                                                                            
[13] "• Manage merit pay"                                                                                          
[14] ""                                                                                                            
[15] "• Perform other duties as assigned"
```

Comment: the gsub(test, pattern = "(?<=\n|\r|^)o ", replacement = "• ", perl = TRUE) worked perfectly. Yes this is a single value so this solutions worked. Was confused with the individual lines, they are all still a single value since they all live in a single cell of the data frame, not in multiple rows. That was the trick. And the lookbehind sure did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any lookbehind here, use `^` with `(?m)` flag:

```r
test <- gsub(test, pattern = "(?m)^o ", replacement = "• ", perl=TRUE)
```

The `(?m)` redefines the behavior of the `^` anchor that means "start of a line" if you specify the `m` flag.

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/0sXsel):

```r
test <- "• Direct the Department’s technical\n\no Set direction to ensure goals and objectives\n\no Select management and other key personnel"
cat(gsub(test, pattern = "(?m)^o ", replacement = "• ", perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
• Direct the Department’s technical

• Set direction to ensure goals and objectives

• Select management and other key personnel
```